# UIPasteboard for enterprise apps

Tags: ios, copy-paste, uipasteboard, device-management

I have a situation where I need to enable copy/paste only among a bunch of enterprise apps on a managed device.

This lead me to UIPasteboard, but looks like for such a feature we need all apps to be in the same app group.

Is there a possibility to restrict copy/paste (and other menu options) to only some applications (not in the same app group) ?

I am only aware of custom named UIPasteboards, couldn't find any other hint in documentations or wwdc videos.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If your app are in the seam group, consider using the keychain group

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this is the issue, the apps can’t be in the same group, they’re all managed though